# Force plot to have a special size or to increase the distance between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to generate a plot by matplotlib that three graphs are in a row and axes have names. Unfortunately the dimension is in a way that labels run into the other graphs. How can I avoid this?

Note: I just changed my code to make it a template in order to show the problem I am discussing of!

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from bisect import bisect_left,bisect_right
import numpy as np
global ranOnce
ranOnce=False
def threeLines(x):
    """Draws a function which is a combination of two lines intersecting in
    a point one with a large slope and one with a small slope.
    """
    start=0
    mid=5
    end=20
    global ranOnce,slopes,intervals,intercepts;
    if(not ranOnce):
        slopes=np.array([5,0.2,1]);
        intervals=[start,mid,end]
        intercepts=[start,(mid-start)*slopes[0]+start,(end-mid)*slopes[1]+(mid-start)*slopes[0]+start]
#        plt.plot(X,Y)
#        plt.axis('equal')
#        plt.show()
        ranOnce=True;
    place=bisect_left(intervals,x)
    if place==0:
        y=(x-intervals[place])*slopes[place]+intercepts[place];
    else:    
        y=(x-intervals[place-1])*slopes[place-1]+intercepts[place-1];
    return y;
def threeLinesDrawer(minimum,maximum):
    t=np.arange(minimum,maximum,1)
    fig=plt.subplot(131)
    markerSize=400;
    fig.scatter([minimum,maximum],[threeLines(minimum),threeLines(maximum)],marker='+',s=markerSize)
#    fig.set_xlim(minimum-1,maximum+1)
#    fig.set_ylim(nLines(minimum)-1,nLines(maximum)+1) 

    y=np.zeros(len(t));
    for i in range(len(t)):
        y[i]=int(threeLines(t[i]))
    fig.scatter(t,y)
    fig.grid(True)
    fig.set_xlabel('Y')
    fig.set_ylabel('X')
def threeLinesDrawer2(minimum,maximum):
    t=np.arange(minimum,maximum,1)
    fig=plt.subplot(132)
    markerSize=400;
    fig.scatter([minimum,maximum],[threeLines(minimum),threeLines(maximum)],marker='+',s=markerSize)
#    fig.set_xlim(minimum-1,maximum+1)
#    fig.set_ylim(nLines(minimum)-1,nLines(maximum)+1) 

    y=np.zeros(len(t));
    for i in range(len(t)):
        y[i]=int(threeLines(t[i]))
    fig.scatter(t,y)
    fig.grid(True)
    fig.set_xlabel('Y')
    fig.set_ylabel('X')
def threeLinesDrawer3(minimum,maximum):
    t=np.arange(minimum,maximum,1)
    fig=plt.subplot(133)
    markerSize=400;
    fig.scatter([minimum,maximum],[threeLines(minimum),threeLines(maximum)],marker='+',s=markerSize)
#    fig.set_xlim(minimum-1,maximum+1)
#    fig.set_ylim(nLines(minimum)-1,nLines(maximum)+1) 

    y=np.zeros(len(t));
    for i in range(len(t)):
        y[i]=int(threeLines(t[i]))
    fig.scatter(t,y)
    fig.grid(True)
    fig.set_xlabel('Y')
    fig.set_ylabel('X')
threeLinesDrawer(0,20)
threeLinesDrawer2(0,20)
threeLinesDrawer3(0,20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I believe my question is crystal clear and completely follows the FAQs obligations. I would be happy to know why I received a minus vote??

Comment: I did not downvote the question, but I think that your example is very verbose. You are asking about space in between subplots, do we really care what the content of the plots are? Do I need to know that `markerSize=400;`?

Comment: @Hooked, They are many lousy people here who just downvote because you didn't give any example and illustrated the problem! So yes! at least I put an example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the padding between plots.  Just before the last line of your script, add something like

```
plt.tight_layout(w_pad=0.4)
```

You can play with 0.4, to adjust it as you see fit.  Here, the `w` is for width.  In other cases, you might also want to adjust the height padding with `h_pad`, or both at the same time with `pad`.

This is a relatively new command (new in v1.1), so you may have to upgrade matplotlib if you don't have it.